# Using dplyr::filter within plumber

Tags: r, dplyr, plumber

I have a plumber API and would like to return a value based on filtering through dplyr. I would usually use quotes in filtering (`group == "a"`), but I'm not sure what to do here.

```
library(plumber)

#* @apiTitle Test filtering

df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "b", "c"), 
             var1 = c(3, 1, 2), 
             var2 = c( 2,  4, 8))

#* Return one value
#* @param "my_group" My Group
#* @post /my_output

function(group) {

  df %>%
    filter(group == my_group) %>%
    select(var1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like

```
#* Return one value
#* @param my_group My Group
#* @get /values
function(my_group) {
  df %>%
    filter(group == my_group) %>%
    select(var1)
}
```

Then you can use a URL like `/values?my_group=a`. The parameters will come through with strings so you don't need to worry about quotes. If you really wanted to have the same variable name, you could do

```
#* Return one value
#* @param group My Group
#* @get /values
function(group) {
  df %>%
    filter(.data$group == .env$group) %>%
    select(var1)
}
```

So you have `/values?group=a`

These will work with POST requests as well, it's just easier to show the GET URL.